# inserting a title for a pop up window in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm trying to insert a title in a popup window as follows:

It is in the head element and the title attribute is instantiated. However when I call my javascript window.open method, the window is created and shows "untitled". If I expand the width of the window then I'm seeing what the title should have been.

[image: Initially:]

[image: if i manually expand the width]
Does anyone know how to fix this? It's specific with google chrome only since I tested it in firefox and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Possibly similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570860/chrome-popup-window-names.  Might be a Chrome bug.

Comment: Darm I didnt see that question. Thanks, I believe now its a bug. BTW, isnt chrome suppose to be the best browser?

Comment: I guess nothing's perfect?  Still beats the types of bugs you'll find in IE!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with Chrome. However, there is a workaround for this.

If you put the following script in the page that opens in the popup window, it seems to work fine.

`<script language"text/javascript">
this.window.resizeBy(1,1);
this.window.resizeBy(-1,-1);
</script>`